# c#, issue with constructor using variable as name of new object

Tags: c#, object, constructor

I don't want all of the objects to have the same name.
I'm trying to use a variable (input from the user) to create the object.

Why can I not do this ? :)

```
public class Student
{
   public static int Count = 0;
   public int ID   { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   Dictionary<int, Student> students = new Dictionary<int, Student>();
   public Student (string name, int id)
   {
      Name = name;
      ID = id;
   }
   public static void addStudent()
   {
      Student.Count++;                                // incrementing value for new student id.
      Console.Write("Please enter student's name: "); // grabbing input from user.
      string studentName = Console.ReadLine();
      Console.WriteLine("Student ID value: {0}", Student.Count); // for testing.
      int studentID = Student.Count;
      /* Student (studentName) = new Student (studentName, studentID) -- The issue is with this line*/
      Student added = new Student(studentName, studentID) // using this as a temp for now.
         {
            Name = studentName,
            ID = studentID
         };
   }
}
```

Comment: Hi, your code compiles. What is the exact problem?

Comment: O wait... you marked it as comment.

Comment: You can't dynamically name your class instances, but you can modify their internal values such as name. Why not just create a new `List<Student>` and then append to that?

Comment: I commented out the line of code I want to use: "Student (studentName) = new Student (studentName, studentID)". I can't use this code because it's a variable I'm assuming ? I don't want "added" as the name for each new object created. Make sense ?

Comment: I think you need to separate your concerns a little here

Comment: If adding each student to a list is the best approach, I will research and add them that way. My plan was to create the object, add them to a dictionary using the static variable count as one value, and the student name as another.

Comment: `addStudent` and `Students` dictionary should not be part of the `student` class.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns

Comment: I'll read up on that. Thanks for all of the responses. Will creating each student and adding them to a list be the easiest way to approach this ?

Comment: And: you cannot access non static members from a static method unless they are passed as arguments.

Comment: I see no reason to use a dictionary. With a list, their index + 1 will be the same as count anyway if you need to reference it for some reason (assuming you add them to the list as they are created) . You can also store more than just two fields considering you're storing the entire object.

Comment: Makes perfect sense. Sorry for the ignorant questions. Have a great weekend! :)

Comment: Ha, no problem, enjoy your code-ride ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to house all the students in the dictionary? If that's the case, you might want to make the dictionary static. Otherwise, each instance of the student will have their own unique dictionary. I'd seperate the dictionary from the student though.

Try:

```
public class Student
{
    public static int Count = 0;
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public static Dictionary<int, Student> students = new Dictionary<int, Student>();
    public Student(string name, int id)
    {
        Name = name;
        ID = id;
    }
    public static void addStudent()
    {
        Student.Count++;                                // incrementing value for new student id.
        Console.Write("Please enter student's name: "); // grabbing input from user.
        string studentName = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Student ID value: {0}", Student.Count); // for testing.
        int studentID = Student.Count;
        /* Student (studentName) = new Student (studentName, studentID) -- The issue is with this line*/
        Student added = new Student(studentName, studentID);
        bool IDInUse = students.ContainsKey(added.ID);
        if(IDInUse)
        {
            students[added.ID] = added;
        }
        else
        {
            students.Add(added.ID, added);
        }

    }
}
```

Not really the best set up overall and you run the risk of easily overriding existing students but it'll get in started in the right direction. But like I said, I highly recommend separating the two. If you delete the second student, but add a new one, it wouldn't replace your second student, but your third.

I suggest making a separate class for the dictionary.

```c#
public class Student
{
    private string Name;
    public Guid ID { get; private set; }

    public Student(string name)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.ID = new Guid();
    }
}

public class StudentDirectory
{
    public Dictionary<Guid, Student> Directory { get; private set; }

    public StudentDirectory() : this(new Dictionary<Guid, Student>())
    { }

    public StudentDirectory(Dictionary<Guid, Student> directory)
    {
        this.Directory = directory;
    }

    public void AddStudent(Student entry)
    {
        bool idExists = Directory.ContainsKey(entry.ID);
        if(idExists)
        {
            Directory[entry.ID] = entry;
        }
        else
        {
            Directory.Add(entry.ID, entry);
        }
    }

    public void AddStudent()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the new stuent's name.\n");
        string name = Console.ReadLine();
        Student entry = new Student(name);
        AddStudent(entry);
    }
}
```

A GUID (globally unique identifier) will help with preventing overwrites. Additionally we can add existing students or instantiate one with the same method.

Answer (score 0):

One way may be:

```
static class Program
{
    public class Student
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Student(int ID, string Name)
        {
            this.Name = Name;
            this.ID = ID;
        }
    }

    public class Students : List<Student>
    {
        public void Add()
        {
            Console.Write("Please enter student's name: ");
            string studentName = Console.ReadLine();
            int studentID = base.Count + 1;
            Console.WriteLine("Student ID value: {0}", studentID);
            base.Add(new Student(studentID, studentName));
        }
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        Students students = new Students();
        students.Add();
    }
}
```

if you want to all student presents in student class then you can define it as static, but it is not recommanded.

```
public class Student
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Student(int ID, string Name)
    {
        this.Name = Name;
        this.ID = ID;
    }
    public static List<Student> AllStudents = new List<Program.Student>();
    public static void AddStudent()
    {
        Console.Write("Please enter student's name: ");
        string studentName = Console.ReadLine();
        int studentID = AllStudents.Count + 1;
        Console.WriteLine("Student ID value: {0}", studentID);
        AllStudents.Add(new Student(studentID, studentName));
    }
}
```

But as an example of OOP model in real problem, students list may needed in classroom, then you should assign all students to a classroom. supposing this, you can define classes as follow:

```
class Student
{
    public int id;
    public string name;
}

class ClassRoom
{
    public int classId;
    public string className;
    public string lessonName;
    public DateTime startDate, endDate;
    .
    .
    .
    public List<Student> students = new List<Student>();
}

void Main()
{
    Student Adam = new Student(11, "Adam");
    Student Hussein = new Student(12, "Hussein");
    Student John = new Student(13, "John");

    ClassRoom Class1 = new ClassRoom{classId:1, className: "Class1", lessonName="Math"};
    Class1.students.Add(Adam);
    Class1.students.Add(Hussein);

    ClassRoom Class2 = new ClassRoom{classId:2, className: "Class2", lessonName="Physics"};
    Class1.students.Add(Adam);
    Class1.students.Add(John);
}
```

You can check weather the `student.id` is duplicate or not and so on... this is not related to OOP concepts.